# HTML and CSS: how to make rounded corners on tables main corners

Tags: html, css

How am I supposed to exactly have 4 corners of this table to be rounded, I tried border-radius{ on table{ and it still doesnt work, and if do on the cells, it rounds every cells, i just want the main 4 corners of the table to be round?

```
table{
    /*removing the borders between the cells*/
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-size: 14px;
    /*table shadow*/
    box-shadow: 0 6px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    margin-top: 40px ;
    width: 70%;
    height: 60%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qy4r3wn9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have to add

```
table { overflow: hidden; }
```

in order to let the (invisible) border actually snip off the content inside. Currently, if you were to make the border visible (`border: 1px solid red;`) you'll see that your curved corners work just fine, but that the cell contents just stick out beyond the border.